# How to permanently delete files (like images) from Bitnami Parse API server from dashboard?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, bitnami

I just installed Bitnami Parse sever API. I used Putty for Windows and created EC2 instance in AWS. I am new to all these things, so I don't fully understand how all of these things work.

I made an android app where users can upload images. But now when I go to Bitnami Parse API dashboard and get the image URL and then later delete the row containing images, and paste the earlier copied URL in browser, the image is still there and I can access it.

How to permanently delete the files from Parse API dashboard or via code and will this affect my storage limit (I am using AWS free tier)?

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API for that as described in the documentation: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#deleting-files

```
curl -X DELETE \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: ${MASTER_KEY}" \
  https://YOUR.PARSE-SERVER.HERE/parse/files/MY_FILE_NAME.png
```